# Warning message when leaving a page without saving

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm trying to display a warning on my page when someone tries to leave one of the forms without saving. After some googling I found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        console.log("Message");
        return "If you exit this page you will lose your data!";
    }
</script>
```

I put it in my views and it did display a message, albeit not the one I programmed (probably generated by the browser). The problem with that is that it does not matter how the user tries to leave the page. Even if they click the commit button, the warning still pops up. Is there a way to set a condition when this should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deactivate the warning with:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Put that inside a listener that listens for your Confirm/Save click.

Comment: I added a listener using document.getElementById("<name>").addEventListener("click", function(){window.onbeforeunload = null;}, but the warning shows up regardless. Since the message is created by chrome, not the message I wrote, is it possible that chrome creates this whenever onbeforeunload is called anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure it's being called? You're missing a ")", but maybe that's just in your comment. It works here jsfiddle.net/bqwcf4ua/1. Either click Save or somewhere that isn't save, then try reloading the page.